# What are the 'best' variables out there to forecast accurately GDP and inflation according to macro literature?

Tags: macroeconomics, time-series

What are the best variables out there to forecast accurately GDP and inflation according to macro literature?

I'd like to forecast the next quarter, not the long-run.

Some time-series ideas I gathered:

- industry production
- employment
- important export-import partners production
- business confidence indexes (e.g. INSEE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to do this in real time which means you want to do a [nowcasting](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304393208000652). This is tricky because many economic series are revised, which means you also need [real time data](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1162/003465303322369768) (what were the figures when released rather than what is known with hindsight).

The Atlanta Federal Reserve Bank uses this approach in their [GDP Now](https://www.frbatlanta.org/cqer/research/gdpnow.aspx?panel=1) product. You should check out their methodology and inputs to get started on your attempt.

> The growth rate of real gross domestic product (GDP) measured by the
>   U.S. Bureau of Economic Analysis (BEA) is a key metric of the pace of
>   economic activity. It is one of the four variables included in the
>   economic projections of Federal Reserve Board members and Bank
>   presidents for every other Federal Open Market Committee (FOMC)
>   meeting. As with many economic statistics, GDP estimates are released
>   with a lag whose timing can be important for policymakers. For
>   example, of the four scheduled 2014 release dates of an “advance” (or
>   first) estimate of GDP growth, two are on the second day of a
>   scheduled FOMC meeting with the other two on the day after the
>   meeting. In preparation for FOMC meetings, policymakers have the Fed
>   Board staff projection of this “advance” estimate at their disposal.
>   These projections—available through 2008 at the Philadelphia Fed’s
>   Real Time Data Center—have generally been more accurate than forecasts
>   from simple statistical models. As stated by economists Jon Faust and
>   Jonathan H. Wright in a 2009 paper, “by mirroring key elements of the
>   data construction machinery of the Bureau of Economic Analysis, the
>   Fed staff forms a relatively precise estimate of what BEA will
>   announce for the previous quarter’s GDP even before it is announced.”
>
> The Atlanta Fed GDPNow model also mimics the methods used by the BEA
>   to estimate real GDP growth. The GDPNow forecast is constructed by
>   aggregating statistical model forecasts of 13 subcomponents that
>   comprise GDP. Other private forecasters use similar approaches to
>   “nowcast” GDP growth. However, these forecasts are not updated more
>   than once a month or quarter, are not publicly available, or do not
>   have forecasts of the subcomponents of GDP that add “color” to the
>   top-line number. The Atlanta Fed GDPNow model fills these three voids.
>
> The BEA’s advance estimates of the subcomponents of GDP use publicly
>   released data from the U.S. Census Bureau, U.S. Bureau of Labor
>   Statistics, and other sources. Much of this data is displayed in the
>   BEA’s Key Source Data and Assumptions table that accompanies the
>   “advance” GDP estimate. GDPNow relates these source data to their
>   corresponding GDP subcomponents using a “bridge equation” approach
>   similar to the one described in a Minneapolis Fed study by Preston J.
>   Miller and Daniel M. Chin. Whenever the monthly source data is not
>   available, the missing values are forecasted using econometric
>   techniques similar to those described in papers by James H. Stock and
>   Mark W. Watson and Domenico Giannone, Lucrezia Reichlin, and David
>   Small. A detailed description of the data sources and methods used in
>   the GDPNow model is provided in an accompanying Atlanta Fed working
>   paper.
>
> As more monthly source data becomes available, the GDPNow forecast for
>   a particular quarter evolves and generally becomes more accurate. That
>   said, the forecasting error can still be substantial just prior to the
>   “advance” GDP estimate release. It is important to emphasize that the
>   Atlanta Fed GDPNow forecast is a model projection not subject to
>   judgmental adjustments. It is not an official forecast of the Federal
>   Reserve Bank of Atlanta, its president, the Federal Reserve System, or
>   the FOMC.